# how to use sharepoint from behind cleaos

Tags: sharepoint

I have Sharepoint on the cloud and I can access it from anywhere, except home. At home I have a ClearOS and I can´t go through to my Sharepoint Portal.

I guess that I may need to open some ports, right? Whic ports?

Answer (score 1):

Port 80.  SharePoint runs as a normal website, unless you're trying to access Central Admin or using SharePoint Designer.

You shouldn't need to explicitly open port 80, especially if you can access other websites.

**You should post more info about any errors you are getting.**

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to have your Sharepoint site bypassed in the proxy server settings section. Sharepoint can use proprietary bits (ikr? Microsoft doing something proprietary?) that get borked when passing through the proxy or content filter.

If you list the site(s) in the Web Proxy module (bypass section at the bottom) it will create appropriate firewall rules that will skip over using the proxy and content filter for that site.

Cheers.